# What happens to unbound JavaScript literals?

Tags: javascript

What happens to JavaScript literals (strings, numbers) that are not bound (aka assigned) to a variable ?

```
// A comment
"Practically, also a comment"
var assigned = "something"
53
423.0022 
NaN
"does it impact performance"
// or is it treated just like a comment?
```

The browser appears to ignore them, but I couldn't find a specific rule in the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)

Comment: For reference: [Expression Statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-expression-statement)

Comment: I don't follow ES3.1, but must be added the strict mode (it's detected through a String literal inside an expression statement by the way)

Comment: It's likely that real world JS engines optimise away "unused" expressions that have no side effects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are "expression statements". Such expressions are evaluated, but since they are not assigned, their value is not stored. JavaScript engines are likely to detect those that have no side effects, and eliminate them as if they were never there.

But still at least one of those has an effect:

```
 "use strict";
```

This has the meaning of a [JavaScript directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/use-strict-directive)

From the [EcmaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-directive-prologues-and-the-use-strict-directive):

> A Use Strict Directive is an *ExpressionStatement* in a Directive Prologue whose *StringLiteral* is either the exact code unit sequences `"use strict"` or `'use strict'`.

Also note that other string literals *may* have a special meaning when used in the directive prologue:

> Implementations may define implementation specific meanings for *ExpressionStatement* productions which are not a Use Strict Directive and which occur in a Directive Prologue.

Comment: That's a directive literal statement, not a string literal expression - try entering it in https://astexplorer.net/

Comment: And note that the strict mode is added since ES3.1: http://jaoo.dk/dl/jaoo-aarhus-2008/slides//PratapLakshman_ECMAScript31.pdf (after ES4)

Comment: @joews, I think that is a matter of word choice. The EcmaScript spec speaks of it as a string literal of an expression statement in a directive prologue.

Comment: That's good to know. I was going from the AST Node type that Babylon uses (DirectiveLiteral) vs a regular string literal (StringLiteral).

Answer (score 5):

It's just an [expression statement](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-expression-statement) that evaluates - without side effects - to a value that is discarded.

You can see it's the result of the statement if you try this in `eval` or a REPL.

Answer (score 1):

The values are stored in memory, until they get cleaned up by the Garbage collector, since nothing is pointing to that place in memory.

Comment: I don't think the garbage collector is involved in this. Do you have a reference for that? I would think the memory used to evaluate the expression is immediately freed, if at all the engine has produced byte code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value is not being stored (i.e. no space is being allocated to hold your literal), it is more or less being ignored by the browser, and also no overhead for the garbage collector. At least the function of your code does not change. Your javascript file will of course be a tiny bit larger because it contains more (useless) text.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to treat them as variables being inserted to nothing. It treats them as if they don't exist anyway. Try it:

```js
function myFunction() {
  "comment"
  //Or comment
  alert("hello");
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Call Javascript</button>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, nothing happens when the empty string is there. This is an interesting question, so I would be very interested in hearing any other results.